# Designing html with css to print on a4 size layout

Tags: php, css, xml, excel, xslt

I have to read data from excel file and display as a HTML format to generate a report which prints on an A4 size sheet. The A4 size sheet already has a layout designed like a bill or an invoice copy. I have to design my html page calculating and properly aligning the contents with the Bill Layout.

I read from a csv file using php and generated xml which is linked with a xslt.

Question is how do i design the layout to fit it in my given format to be printed on a a4 size certificate or invoice copy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would be better off making a pdf

Comment: Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a digital image of the bill, you could set it as the html background and move things around to fit the layout of the bill and then try to print it with out the background or just print the whole thing on blank paper instead of getting the bills printed separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what could be size of the digital image for an a4 size sheet

Comment: You mean in file size or document  dimensions?

Comment: The dimensions of A4 is 297 x 210 mm or 11.69 x 8.27 inches. It has an area of 0.062 m², which corresponds to 0.07 square yards, 0.65 square foot, or 93 square inches. When usual and recommended printing margins are put , the printable size of A4 is 247 x 170 mm.        http://www.all-size-paper.com/A4/a4-paper-size.php